# Get the values form NoUiSlider with two handles

Tags: nouislider

Documentation says to get the current value use `slider.noUiSlider.get();`. But in case of a slider with two handles (and thus two values), how do I get these two seperate values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a slider with two handles, the result of `slider.noUiSlider.get()` is `[firstValue, secondValue]`. All events provide this array as a parameter, as well as the handle index (0/1), allowing to map the two.

```
slider.noUiSlider.on('update', function(values, handle) {
    // value for updated handle is in values[handle]
});
```